# What is the rationale for \r and \n meaning different things in s command?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, whitespace, history-of

We all know that, when searching, `\n` is newline and `\r` is carriage return (`^M`), but when replacing `\r` is newline while `\n` is a null byte (`^@`).

What is the origin of this asymmetry? Given that this behavior is... peculiar to say the least (and quite counterproductive when you get it wrong the first time) I expect there's some bizarre historical reason.

(incidentally, is there some way to "fix" this behavior and get something more intuitive?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At the most basic level, there's already an asymmetry between the search and replace portions of `:substitute` because the former is a regular expression and the latter is text, with specific additional [escape sequences](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-special).  This is just highlighted by the intuition you have about what `\n` means.

For example, consider that `\n` in the search doesn't match a literal `\n`.  It matches the end of line (EOL) byte sequence, which may be `\r`, `\r\n`, or just `\n` depending on the `'fileformat'` of the buffer.

As far as why `\r` is used to mean "insert an EOL", there's some [history](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#NL-used-for-Nul) behind that.  Vi had no way to handle a NUL byte in a file.  Vim improved on that by replacing NUL bytes with an NL byte internally (since C strings are NUL delimited).

This implementation detail leaked into the behavior of `:substitute` since `\n` in the replacement is simply inserted into the internal representation of that line, which is used to indicate a NUL byte.  `\r` inserts an EOL, breaking the internal line in two.  Vim doesn't actually store the EOL bytes in memory, instead (de)serializing them when reading/writing the buffer.

It can't be changed now without breaking the many scripts and the muscle memory of many users.  Thankfully, it's documented in [`:help sub-replace-special`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-special).

Answer (score 6):

A `NUL` byte is a string terminator in C, and for this reason Vim uses this convention, described in the manual at `:h NL-used-for-Nul`:

> <Nul> characters in the file are stored as <NL> in memory.  In the display they are shown as "^@".  The translation is done when reading and writing files.  To match a <Nul> with a search pattern you can just enter CTRL-@ or "CTRL-V 000".  This is probably just what you expect.  Internally the character is replaced with a <NL> in the search pattern.  What is unusual is that typing CTRL-V CTRL-J also inserts a <NL>, thus also searches for a <Nul> in the file. {Vi cannot handle <Nul> characters in the file at all}

This convention has spilled over to the `:s/.../.../` command, but not to the `substitute()` function.  `\r` and `\n` in replacement strings in `substitute()` calls keep their original meaning.

I don't think there are deeper reasons for either behaviour.  Vim has simply evolved organically from the original `vi`.  There never was any big blueprint for it, features were just piled on top of each other, with relatively little effort to keep them organized.

Answer (score 1):

Other Vi clones do not support `\r` or `\n` (as a real backslash and letter) in substitution, but the behaviour of a real `^M` (<kbd>CTRL-V</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>) meaning to split the line into two lines is [standard behavior](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html#tag_20_40_13_40):

> Entering a <carriage-return> in *repl* (which requires an escaping <backslash> in *ex* mode and an escaping <control>-V in open or *vi* mode) shall split the line at that point, creating a new line in the edit buffer. The <carriage-return> shall be discarded.

In the Unix History archive, the first version of BSD ex/vi it appears in is 4.1cBSD ([`@(#)ex_re.c 7.2 10/16/81`](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.1cBSD/usr/src/ucb/ex/ex_re.c), and is not present in 4BSD ([`@(#)ex_re.c 6.2 10/23/80`](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4BSD/usr/src/cmd/ex/ex_re.c)) [4.1a and 4.1b are not present in the archive].

The relevant code is:

```
/* ^V <return> from vi to split lines */
if (c == '\r')
    c = '\n';
```

This is also mentioned in the [news file](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.1cBSD/usr/src/ucb/ex/ex.news):

> It is now possible to split lines with substitute commands from vi, by using ^V<return> in the rhs.  This takes care of the last good reason for using ex command mode.

The previously supported behavior in ex command mode was for backslash-enter (i.e. backslash followed by a real newline) to insert a newline.

Answer (score 1):

The origin of the asymmetry goes back a ways into computing history.

Short version:

```
<CR> & <LF>  (Carriage-Return and Linefeed) 
== 
\r & \n
```

Long version:
The first screens were basically digital versions of teletypes (TTY) and used control codes to generate similar behavior to printers.  Carriage-return took the cursor (or print-head) to the start column.  Linefeed advanced to the next row (on a screen) and fed the paper forward one line.

For printers, you had to do a paired `<CR><LF>` or your output would not look right.  On early screens, the issue still held true.

DOS (and sorta-Windows after) followed the old standard and saves text with `<CRLF>`.

*NIX text (as most vi users are familiar) only uses `<LF>` for efficiency.

To test in Windows, use Word/Wordpad and save a few lines of text "as type: Text - MS-DOS format".  Then open that same file in Notepad.  It should look normal.  Then save the same file in Word/Wordpad "as type: Text".  Notepad will ignore all newlines and run the lines together.  [Notepad's text format defaults to the `\r\n` combination while Word/Wordpad default to `\n`.]

\r is the code equivalent of `<CR>`

\n is the code equivalent of `<LF>`

And in my (very limited) experience with vi, it would try to "fix" the `<CRLF>` combination from my DOS text editor.  vi ended up removing one character, replacing with `<NUL>`.  A big part of the reason I stopped using vi.

Comment: While all your information is interesting, it only tells why `\r` is `<CR>` and `\n` is `<LF>`. It doesn't address the actual question of why `\n\r` behave *differently* in different contexts.

Comment: Thank you! :-)  I was changing it when you replied.   (Added last paragraph.)

Comment: Your test won't work in modern Notepad on Windows 10; Notepad has been changed to detect and handle Unix newline format. (There's a little box at the bottom of the window that will display which format it's using.) You can see an example [here](https://imgur.com/a/G3h0rBV).