# Why \r means newline when replacing?

Tags: substitute

In vim's manual:

```
When replacing: \r is newline, \n is a null byte (0x00).
```

The `\n`'s value is `0x0a` in hex format,it is no relation with `0x00` ,what is the logic to define  `When replacing: \r is newline, \n is a null byte (0x00).`?

Comment: in short, that is an implementation detail, that leaks into the usage

Comment: to me this is a duplicate of [What is the rationale for \r and \n meaning different things in s command?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9386/1841)